# Junit mock throwing completion exception from private methods using completable future chain

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test

I've this public method in service class which has chain of CompletableFuture

```
public InfoResponse getInfoFromService(Request request) {
    ...
    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> allInfosResult = new ArrayList<>();
      for (Info info : infoList) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> singleInfoResult =
                getSingleInfoResult(request, resultFileWriter, exceptions, info);
        allInfosResult.add(singleInfoResult);
    }
    ...
}

private CompletableFuture<Void> getSingleInfoResult(Request request, JsonGenerator resultFileWriter, List<Throwable> exceptions, InfoResponse info) {
    return getInfoKeysListAsync(request, info, exceptions)
            .thenApplyAsync(
                    singleInfoRequests -> {
                      return getSingleInfoKeyResult(resultFileWriter, exceptions, singleInfoRequests);
                    },
                    executor)
            .thenCompose(
                    future -> CompletableFuture.allOf(future.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)))
            .exceptionally(
                    ex -> {
                      exceptions.add(ex);
                      return null;
                    });
}

private List<CompletableFuture<Void>> getSingleInfoKeyResult(JsonGenerator resultFileWriter, List<Throwable> exceptions, List<InfoRequest> infoRequests) {
    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> singleInfoKeyResult = new ArrayList<>();
    for (InfoRequest infoRequest : infoRequests) {
      CompletableFuture<Void> infoKeyResult = getInfoAndWriteAsync(infoRequest, resultFileWriter, exceptions);
      singleInfoKeyResult.add(infoKeyResult);
    }
    return singleInfoKeyResult;
}

private CompletableFuture<Void> getInfoAndWriteAsync(InfoRequest infoRequest, JsonGenerator resultFileWriter, List<Throwable> exceptions) {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(
            () -> {
              // Get Info and write to file logic
            }, ioExecutor)
        .exceptionally(
            ex -> {
              exceptions.add(ex);
              return null;
            });
}

private CompletableFuture<List<InfoRequest>> getInfoKeysListAsync(
      InfoRequest infoRequest, InfoResponse info, List<Throwable> exceptions) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            // Get info keys logic
            )
        .exceptionally(
            ex -> {
              exceptions.add(ex);
              return null;
            });
}
```

In my test I'm trying to mock the exception by mocking CompletableFuture itself like this, but it's not working  -

```
MockedStatic<CompletableFuture> completableFutureMock = mockStatic(CompletableFuture.class);
CompletableFuture<ResponseType> failure = failedFuture(new InterruptedException());
completableFutureMock.when(() -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(any(), any(Executor.class))).thenReturn(failure); //failure is null and so not able to get into exceptionally block
completableFutureMock.when(() -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(any(), any(Executor.class))).thenReturn(failure);

service.getInfoFromService(request);
```

How can I get the exception thrown and assert the list of exceptions in test?